# Simplify a complex regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a way to simplify a regular expression which consists of values (e.g. 12345), relation signs (<,>,<=,>=) and junctors (&,!). E.g. the expression:

```
>= 12345 & <=99999 & !55555
```

should be matched. I have this regular expression:

```
(^<=|^<= | ^>= | ^>= |^<|^>|^< |^> |^)((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
```

I am especially unhappy with the repetition of <=, >=, <, > at the beginning and end of the expression. I would be glad to get a hint how to make it simpler e.g. look ahead, look back.

Comment: what would you want the result to be?

Comment: Please show some matches and results, and maybe some example non-matches. This will help us understand what you are looking to do.

Comment: If an expression can be of arbitrary length, then you might want to do something a little more hands-on than regular expressions, otherwise it will get quite ugly and difficult to read.

Comment: this looks like something that could be much easier to express using a context free grammar (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

Comment: @jeff If it's really only a sequence of alternating numbers and ops, then CFG might still be an overkill.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Maybe, but I've found that with the proper tools a CFG is only a couple of lines, and solves these problems nicely.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun What tool do you have in mind? Would antlr fit the bill?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I use flex/bison with a couple of skeletons. You write a few regexes for the tokens, and, if necessary, a few parser rules to string them together. The skeleton makefile compiles and away you go. See [here](https://github.com/srathbun/example-parser) for a somewhat complex example.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your regex, you can do this simplification steps:

```
 (^<=|^<= | ^>= | ^>= |^<|^>|^< |^> |^)((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
```

1. Move the anchor out of the alternation

   ```
   ^(<=|<= |>= |>= |<|>|< |> |)((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```

   Why has there been whitespace before the anchor? (removed that)
2. Move the following whitespace outside and make it optional

   ```
   ^(<=|<=|>=|>=|<|>|<|>|) ?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```
3. Remove the duplicates in the alternations

   ```
   ^(<=|>=|<|>|) ?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```
4. The empty alternative at the end would match the empty string ==> this alternation is optional

   ```
   ^((<=|>=|<|>)? ?)?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```
5. Make the equal sign optional and remove the duplicates

   ```
   ^((<|>)=? ?)?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```
6. The alternation with single characters can be replaced with a character class

   ```
   ^([<>]=? ?)?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( & > | & < |& >=|&>=|&<=||&<=|&>=|&<|&>|&| &| & |$))*
   ```
7. Do similar things with the alternation at the end and you end up with something like this:

   ```
   ^([<>]=? ?)?((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))( ?(& ?([<>]=?)?)?|$)
   ```

This is untested, I did not change the semantic (I think so), but I did this just here in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all the spaces optional (with question marks) so you don't have to explicitly list all the possibilities. Also you can group the equality/inequality symbols in a character set ([ ]).

Like this, I think

```
(^[<>]=?\s?)((!|)([0-9]{1,5}))(\s?&\s?[<>]=?\s|$)*
```

Comment: This will match '=', not to mention '>=<', '>>', '==>', etc.

Comment: @kevlar1818: Right, but are those likely to occur? [<>]=? is indeed better though,  edited.

Comment: Denying the occurrence of patterns (however improbable the pattern) isn't good regex etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`[<>]=?|\d{1,5}|[&!\|]`

That takes care of your > / >= / < / <= repetition. Seems to work for me.

Let me know if this answers your question, or needs work.

Comment: Nice one @kevlar1818. But won't it catch also ">= <= 12345 & <=99999 & !55555". Do we want it to catch those kind of examples?

Comment: I propose to enhance your answer with `(([<>]=?|!)\s*\d{1,5}\s*)(&\s+([<>]=?|!)\s*\d{1,5}\s*)*`. What do you think @kevlar1818?

Answer (score 0):

I have a two-step procedure in mind. First break by junctor, then check individual parts.

```
final String expr = ">= 12345 & <=99999 & !55555".replaceAll("\\s+", "");
for (String s : expr.split("[|&]"))
  if (!s.matches("([<>]=?|=|!)?\\d+")) { System.out.println("Invalid"); return; }
System.out.println("Valid");
```

But we're still left guessing whether you are talking about validation or something else.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be spending a lot of effort matching optional spaces.  something like `\s?` (0 - 1) or `\s*` (0 - many) would be better.

also, repeated items separated by something are always difficult.  it's best to make a regexp for the "thing" to simplify the repetition.

```
limit = '\s*([<>]=?|!)\s*\d{1,5}\s*'
one_or_more = '^' + limit + '(&' + limit + ')*$'
```

or, expanded out:

```
^\s*([<>]=?|!)\s*\d{1,5}\s*(&\s*([<>]=?|!)\s*\d{1,5}\s*)*$
```

also, `!` is a "relation sign" and not a "junctor" if i am understanding correctly.

(for the people advocating using a "real" parser, the above - the structure of `one_or_more` - is probably how you would end up implementing the &-separated list; there's no need for a parser if you can just use string concatenation in the language).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
^(\s*([<>]=?)?\s*!?\d{1,5}\s*(&|$))*
```

These explanations of sum sub expressions should help you understand the whole thing:

`\s*`: 0 or more spaces
`([<>]=?)?`: A `<` or `>` sign optionally followed by an `=`, all optional
`!?`: And optional `!`
`\d{1,5}`: 1-5 digits
`(&|$)`: Either an `&` or the end of the string